# Errors like "Conflicting types for 'move'" when using Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, macos, declaration

I got a problem with Xcode, that only appears on Xcode. It does not appear in VisualStudio and not even when compiling over the console (on OS X).

Following errors occur:

1. Conflicting types for 'move' (Line 4)
2. Implicit declaration of function 'move' is invalid in C99 (Line 20)
3. Too many arguments to function call, expected 2, have 4 (Line 20)
4. Conflicting types for 'move' (Line 42)

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void printField(int *field);
void move(int *field, int *posX, int *posY, char zug); //line 4

int main() {

    int field[8][8] = { 0 }, posX=0, posY=0;
    char zug;

    // setzen der Spielfigur
    field[posY][posX] = 1;

    printf("\nBeenden mit x\n");

    do {
        printField(&field[0][0]);
        printf("\nZug [w hoch, a links, s runter, d rechts]: ");
        scanf("%c", &zug);
        move(&field[0][0], &posX, &posY, zug); //line 20
    }while(zug != 'x');

    return 0;
}


// Ausgabe Spielfeld
void printField(int *field) {
    printf("\n");
    int i, j;
    // Schleife fuer Zeilen, Y-Achse
    for(i=0; i<8; i++) {
        // Schleife fuer Spalten, X-Achse
        for(j=0; j<8; j++) {
            printf("%d ", *(field+i*8+j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

// Spielfigur bewegen
void move(int *field, int *posX, int *posY, char zug) { //line 42
    // alte Position loeschen
    *(field + *posY * 8 + *posX) = 0;

    // neue Position bestimmen
    switch(zug) {
        case 'w': (*posY)--; break;
        case 'a': (*posX)--; break;
        case 's': (*posY)++; break;
        case 'd': (*posX)++; break;
    }

    // Grenzueberschreitung pruefen
    if(*posX < 0) *posX = 7;
    if(*posX > 7) *posX = 0;
    if(*posY < 0) *posY = 7;
    if(*posY > 7) *posY = 0;

    // neue Position setzen
    *(field + *posY * 8 + *posX) = 1;
}
```

Comment: The compiler surely tells you line numbers with the error messages, right?

Comment: Line 4: Conflicting types for 'move'

Line 20:  Implicit declaration of function 'move' is invalid in C99

Line 20: Too many arguments to function call, expected 2, have 4

Line 42: Conflicting types for 'move'

Comment: Thanks! And now you will for sure annotate the code to tell us which lines are 4, 20 and 42?

Comment: @Eduard Are you sure you're compiling and running the code you've shown? I can't seem to see any problems with your code.

Comment: Anyways, to me this looks as if the `<stdio.h>` in use pulls in an existing declaration of a function called `move()` (specifying 2 but 4 parameters). Try renaming your `move()` to something like `my_move()`.

Comment: @CoolGuy Like I already mentioned, this problem only occurs on Xcode. It's an example code from a how-to Tutorial and I tried that code on Xcode but it could not compile it. So I tried it also on codeblocks and VisualStudio and on both IDE it worked without any problems.

Comment: @alk thanks! This is the solution to this problem.

Comment: @Eduard Do not include solutions in the question. alk has already answered it. You can accept and upvote alk's answer if it worked for you instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Conflicting types for 'move' (Line 4)
> ...
> Too many arguments to function call, expected 2, have 4 (Line 20)
> ```

To me this looks as if the `<stdio.h>` in use pulls in an existing declaration of a function called `move()` (specifying 2 but 4 parameters).

Try renaming your function `move()` to something like `my_move()`.

Comment: @alk Nice Catch! +1 . What does OP's `stdio.h`'s `move` function do?